# Android: How can I find the line of MY OWN code which causes this crash?

Tags: android, debugging, android-arrayadapter, stack-trace

I am getting the following stacktrace from a crash:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 6, size is 2
   at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
   at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:66)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:337)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:390)
   at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
   at android.widget.Spinner.makeAndAddView(Spinner.java:546)
   at android.widget.Spinner.layout(Spinner.java:495)
   at android.widget.Spinner.onLayout(Spinner.java:459)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1652)
   at android.widget.TableRow.onLayout(TableRow.java:123)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
   at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1459)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:907)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:502)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1663)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1521)
   at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
   at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14008)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4373)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1892)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1711)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

How can I find out which line of MY OWN code causes this crash?

Comment: Try creating an exception breakpoint

Comment: which IDE are you using? Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: Android Studio, sorry for this Newbie questions, I am just used to see one of my line code in the stacktrace...

Comment: My guess is that you modified the `ArrayList` directly, rather than using methods on `ArrayAdapter` either to modify its contents or at least call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to indicate that the underlying model is different.

Comment: This looks like a layout/view problem, not a code problem. You might want to double-check your layouts (particularly your Spinner array data) to see if it contains any invalid values.

Comment: @CommonsWare The offending fragment does not even manipulate an ArrayList nor contain one :(

Comment: @adelphus what would be invalid values?

Comment: If this crash is coming from your process, then you have some `Spinner` somewhere, that has an `ArrayAdapter` in it. If you want to fix this crash, you will find this `Spinner`, find this `ArrayAdapter`, and determine how the `ArrayAdapter` is getting out of sync with its underlying `ArrayList`. Whether it is in "the offending fragment" or not does not matter.

Comment: @CommonsWare You were right. I set the spinner'selection to an index out of bounds of its adapter. The only thing which I don't understand, that the offending line of code was not in the stacktrace. If you post your comment as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some crashes will show your code in the stack trace. Others will not. One common "will not" case is a situation like this, where the crash is triggered by something that you did, but the work happens later on the main application thread.

In this case, `Spinner` (apparently) does not validate the selection index right away, so your call to set it did not fail. But, setting the selection adds a job to the main application thread's work queue to re-render this widget. When *that* happened, the selection index was invalid, and you crashed.

In an ideal world, there would be more validation up front, so you would fail on the setter and see more directly the source of your problem. And sometimes that does happen. But sometimes it will not, and you are left with a stack trace like yours. While you cannot directly point at a line in your code and say "Eureka! That's where my problem comes from!", you at least know the basics of what went wrong, and you would need to double-check recent changes you may have made that affect the crashing widget.